# What NTFS attributes could prevent Cygwin from listing a file in a directory?

Tags: windows, filesystems, cygwin, ntfs

I am baffled by the following situation. It seems that I have a file, which looks completely normal in all Windows tools, however does not appear in any directory listings in Cygwin. It is accessible, though, if named explicitly. Observe:

```
$ ls -lA
total 0

$ ls -lA magic.pdf
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Konstantin None 1647075 Oct 11  2017 magic.pdf

$ /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/cmd /C dir
 Volume in drive G is Toshiba Backup
 Volume Serial Number is E692-2E8C

 Directory of G:\test

20/04/2018  11:49    <DIR>          .
20/04/2018  11:49    <DIR>          ..
11/10/2017  19:00         1.647.075 magic.pdf
               1 File(s)      1.647.075 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  483.796.258.816 bytes free
```

It seems that I can do whatever I like with this file (copy, move around, zip and unzip) - as long as I do it via Windows-native tools, the resulting file remains "invisible" to Cygwin (yet appears fine in Windows Explorer, for example). Observe this, for example:

```
$ 7z a magic.zip magic.pdf

7-Zip 18.01 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-01-28

Scanning the drive:
1 file, 1647075 bytes (1609 KiB)

Creating archive: magic.zip

Add new data to archive: 1 file, 1647075 bytes (1609 KiB)


Files read from disk: 1
Archive size: 1499080 bytes (1464 KiB)
Everything is Ok

$ ls
magic.zip

$ mkdir temp
$ cd temp
$ 7z x ../magic.zip

7-Zip 18.01 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-01-28

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 1499080 bytes (1464 KiB)

Extracting archive: ..\magic.zip
--
Path = ..\magic.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 1499080

Everything is Ok

Size:       1647075
Compressed: 1499080

$ ls

$ cmd /C dir
 Volume in drive G is Toshiba Backup
 Volume Serial Number is E692-2E8C

 Directory of G:\test\temp

20/04/2018  11:56    <DIR>          .
20/04/2018  11:56    <DIR>          ..
11/10/2017  19:00         1.647.075 magic.pdf
               1 File(s)      1.647.075 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  483.791.458.304 bytes free
```

If I copy the file with Cygwin, the copy becomes visible to Cygwin:

```
$ cp magic.pdf magic2.pdf
$ ls -lA
total 1612
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Konstantin None 1647075 Apr 20 11:50 magic2.pdf
```

This does not help, however:

```
$ touch magic.pdf
$ ls -lA
total 1612
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Konstantin None 1647075 Apr 20 11:50 magic2.pdf
```

I may move the file around various hard drives. As long as they are NTFS it remains invisible. Moving to FAT32 makes the file visible, hence it seems to be somehow related to NTFS file attributes.

Comparing the properties of the "invisible" file with its cygwin-visible copy, I can see that the former has a note in it's Properties dialog: "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer".
If I check the "unblock" checkbox, the message disappears, yet the file still remains invisible to Cygwin.

Could someone explain me what is happening, and how could I have force Cygwin to see *all* the files (it is a bit frustrating when you backup a directory via rsync and then discover that not all files were transferred).

Cygwin64, recent version, installed on Windows 10 Pro, launched as Administrator.

Comment: Run `attrib.exe magic.pdf` to check the NTFS file attributes. Also check `cmd /c dir /r magic.pdf` to show alternate data streams.

Comment: `attrib.exe` just shows the `A` attribute - nothing different from a "visible" copy. The `dir /r` does show an alternative stream named `magic.pdf:Zone.Identifier:$DATA` which carries 26 bytes (I guess that's where the "downloaded from the Internet" flag is stored). When I check the "unblock" checkbox in the Properties dialog, the stream disappears, however the file is still not visible in Cygwin.

Comment: Maybe `ls` is using an extended attribute. Try `getfattr -d -m '.*' magic.pdf`. This may require installing an "attr" package.

Comment: General OS problems aren't really on topic here. You may have better luck on superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: probably this issue https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2018-03/msg00141.html

Comment: @matzeri  Indeed, the following PowerShell snippet "un-hides" the file: `(Get-Item m.pdf).attributes = 0`, while the following - hides it: `(Get-Item m.pdf).attributes = 0x100`. Strangely, there do not seem to be any other built-in (GUI or CLI) means of viewing or changing the "temporary" attribute. Your observation is thus a valid answer to my question. Write it as an answer, so I'd close the issue.

Comment: That's a bizarre interpretation of [`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg258117) and definitely a "Really Bad Idea".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current cygwin dll 2.10.0 has a bug in handling files and directories with `Temporary` attribute.
This is an obscure file attribute not visible on `ATTRIB` command
nor on explorer file properties. 
These file are usually produced by third parties program and not by cygwin ones.

The bug was correct on development sources
https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2018-03/msg00141.html
and latest snapshots correctly handle them and the files with such attribute are visible to cygwin programs.

As reported by KT

> PowerShell snippet "un-hides" the file: (Get-Item m.pdf).attributes =
>   0, while the following - hides it: (Get-Item m.pdf).attributes =
>   0x100. Strangely, there do not seem to be any other built-in (GUI or
>   CLI) means of viewing or changing the "temporary" attribute.

Power shell can modify the `Temporary` attribute.